# Bloch vector time evolution in magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm wondering if there is a smart way of solving the system of equations

$$\frac{d\vec{n}}{dt} = \gamma (\vec{n} \times \vec{B}(t)),$$

where $\vec{n}(t) = \big(x(t),y(t),z(t) \big)$ is the Bloch vector and $\vec{B}(t) = (B_1\cos\omega t, B_1 \sin \omega t, B_2)$ is the external magnetic field.

By smart I mean faster than just writing it down in matrix form and using methods for solving a system of homogeneous linear equations with variable coefficients. I'm looking for some sort of reference where such a solution is shown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deriving the Bloch vector time evolution equation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160722/)

Comment: $\mathbf n\times\mathbf B$ is linear in $\mathbf n$, so there exists a matrix $\star\mathbf B$ that acts on $\mathbf n$. Hence your system is of the form $\dot{\mathbf n} = \star\mathbf B\mathbf n$. The solution has the form $\mathbf n = e^{\star\mathbf Bt}\mathbf n_0$

Comment: Yes, I figured out the matrix form (btw. is there a reason You denote it with a star?), but the matrix is itself dependent on time, so I don't see how I can just exponentiate?

Comment: oh right didn't notice time dependence, an integral should be taken then. The $\star$ is the Hodge dual.

Comment: What do you mean an integral should be taken? So the solution is $n = e^{\int_0^t dtB(t)} n_0$ ? B(t) is the matrix of course.

Comment: yes but that is more an evocative symbol than a legitimate operation

Comment: How should I understand the matrix integration then? Elementwise? Why is it not a legitimate operation?

Comment: @DepeHb You need to use a [time-ordered exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential) since the matrix may not commute with itself at different times, making the normal exponential ill-defined. Note that solving the general Bloch equations even with constant coefficients involves a fairly tedious calculation. You might want to look into trying to simplify matters by employing the [rotating-wave approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_wave_approximation), if applicable.

Comment: Hmm... Why is nothing about an ordered exponential mentioned here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Systems_of_Linear_Differential_Equations ? I don't know how to proceed if this turns out to be incorrect. I think exponentiating this (calculating eigenvectors) is murder anyway... that's why I was curious if there's some clever way to this.

Comment: In the Wiki article it states that the normal exponential is applicable if $[A(x_1),A(x_2)] = 0$. If this is not true then one must use a path-ordered exponential.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that. But, this won't be true in this case? So my question is, is this even doable analytically (within reason?) with undergraduate tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest a **simple way** which is not without equations, but it is with **very simple equations**. It goes as follows:

You can rotate your system of axes by $\omega t$ around the axis $z$, then by an angle $\theta = arctg(B_1/B_2)$ so as to lay your vector $\vec {B(t)}$ over a new axis $z'$ ? You will get a vector constant in time, of length $B = \sqrt {B_1^2 + B_2^2}$.

In the new axes $x', y', z'$ the system of equations will become

$\frac {d\ n_{x'}}{dt} = \gamma B \ n_{y'}$

$\frac {d\ n_{y'}}{dt} = -\gamma B \ n_{x'}$

and the solution is immediate,

(1) $n_{x'} = cos(\gamma B t)$,$ \ \ \ n_{y'} = -sin(\gamma B t)$.

Whatever is left after this is to reverse the two rotations, i.e. first rotate back around the axis $y'$ by $-\theta$, then, as the axis $z'$ is laid back on $z$, rotate by $-\omega t$ around the axis $z$ for which you have the [rotation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations).